# Multiple line on one Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I am trying to plot multiple line on one chart.

They all have the same X- axis in months, but different observation for y-axis.
I have tried writing this code but I keep on getting an error.
 Can someone point me towards what I am doing wrong?

"Test3" is the same of my data set, "Oil_1" represents the first Y observation, "Oil_2" second observation and "Month" is the X-axis

```
ggplot(test3, + aes(x = Months)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=oil_1),colour="blue")+
    geom_line(aes(y=oil_2),colour="red") +
    ylab(label="Production")+
    xlab("Months")
```

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789737/786542?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra "+" before the first aesthetic call, that could be the problem.

Comment: it is still not working -

Comment: I have tried a different way but now getting thsi error: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: I have used reshape to melt my data as I have two variable

  Months variable value
1      1    OIL_1   183
2      2    OIL_1   172
3      3    OIL_1   890
4      4    OIL_1   876
5      5    OIL_1   345
6      6    OIL_1  2406


then I am entering my ggplot code:

ggplot(TEST3CC, aes(x = Months, y = value)) + 
geom_line(aes(color = variable, linetype = variable)) + 
scale_color_manual(values = c("darkred", "steelblue"))

geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?